# Blazor WASM open an xlss file

Tags: blazor-webassembly, static-files

I have a template Excel file for reports in a Blazor WASM app.
Before creating report I have to open templates.xlsx which is in wwwroot folder.
Unfortunatelly it does not find the file.
I have tried these:

```
FileInfo source = new FileInfo($"{System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"wwwroot/templates.xlsx"}");
```

or

```
using var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("templates.xlsx");
```

How can I open a file in Blazor WASM, please?